# Error when executing a JAR file

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I've been learning about JAR files and wanted to try and create and run one myself. I carried out the following steps:

1. Created a project folder with a 'source' subfolder and a 'classes' subfolder
2. I wrote 2 source files, one with a main method which creates an instance of the other class and runs a simple method in it.
3. Compiled these to the 'classes' subfolder. I checked to see if they would run. They did
4. I created a manifest.txt file and filled in the Main-Class: xxxx and hit the return key. I saved this in the sources subfolder
5. Created a jar file in the classes subfolder by writing

   jar -cvmf manifest.txt zzz.jar *.class
6. Tried to execute the jar file by typing

   java -jar zzz.jar

This gives a ClassNotFound exception. If I try to execute the jar by double clicking on it in windows I get an errorbox saying "Could not find the main class xxxx"

I've double checked the spelling of the class inside the manifest file and it's correct.

Possibly important: I have to compile my programs using java -cp . xyz as there is an issue with my classpath. Does this mean that I need to execute jars in a different way as well? I tried 
   java -cp . -jar zzz.jar
but ended up with the same exception.

Edit: I ended up starting from scratch and now it runs (with the basic -jar zzz.jar command). Frustrating that I don't know what I was doing wrong but glad that it is working!

Comment: @ Sperick: did you verify contents of the jar by jar tf <jar file path>

Comment: I've just done that right now. It includes the 2 class files and the META-INF folder and manifest.mf file

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to supply the entire path of the .class file you wish to execute after the classpath. ie `java -cp xxx.jar classes.mainProgram.class`. Where `classes` is the name of the folder which contains your class files.

Comment: I've tried this. my jar is called test.jar and my class with the main is called classTestMain so I typed in: java -cp test.jar classes.classTestMain.class  This gave me the same exception error

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't number 5. be run in the classes subfolder, where all your class files are? And if your classes are in packages, which they should be, you'll likely want to use * instead of *.class..?

To check what your jar file contains you can run:

```
jar tf zzz.jar
```

Comment: Sorry yes that was a typo. I haven't placed my classes in packages as I'm doing this in steps (from a book) and that'll be the next step after I get this running